# What do the different map room icons mean?

Tags: darkest-dungeon

Sometimes a party member scouts the dungeon, or I find a piece of map, and the mini-map on the screen reveals icons on the room that I imagine is supposed to indicate to me what's in the room. However, I don't see a legend for these anywhere. For instance, in the screenshot below, you can see 4 different icons, but I've seen at least 3 more that aren't represented there.

[image]

What are all the different room icons and what do they mean?

Comment: Since I wasn't at my computer, I grabbed that screenshot from online. I think it might be an older version of the game, because I've never seen a dungeon layout where hallways weren't a straight line, and I think the "Here's where we are" icon has changed to a torch. Still, I'm leaving the screenshot for now just so it's clear what kind of icons I'm talking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At this point I remember six icons.

1. Wooden Door. This is where you **entered the dungeon**.
2. Faded (low-intensity) cavern-looking thing with brick walls. This means **empty**. In the OP's screenshot this was more obviously a brick dungeon room; in the current build the walls seem blank but the bricks are still visible at the bottom.
3. Faded **goblet**. Til I figured out it was a goblet, this to me looked like a monster holding its weird hands over its head; like a freaky scorpion or something. Nope. Goblet. This means treasure; usually from a fountain or some other interactable object. I'd guess that goblet loot skews to provisions and buffs.
4. Golden chest. This room also means treasure, and (almost?) always comes with combat. Treasure is in a **chest**, which may or may not be locked. I'd guest that chest loot skews to heirlooms, trinkets, and gold.
5. Three red figures, slightly slanted. There'll be a **room battle** here.
6. A red skull. This is a **boss** room.

Note that once a room has been cleared, it will change to the #2 Empty icon.

There might be other icons; as I play I'll refine this list.

Comment: I'd like to add that the goblet rooms do often have combat in them as well, altough they are empty from time to time.